# When I use NgFor For Generated Menu, the nested menu is not working and when click on sub-menu, it is not collapsing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When I use `*ngFor` for the menu generated, the nested menu is not working and on clicking on sub-menu, it is not collapsing.

```html
  <li *ngFor="let parent of Menu?.menuList">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-toggle">
      <i class="zmdi zmdi-apps"></i><span>{{parent.displayText}}</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="ml-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let subMenu of parent.subMenu">
        <a [routerLink]="subMenu.accessLink">{{subMenu.displayTextSubMenu}}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details? Are you using any lib in particular? What additional information can you provide that helps tracing the possible issue?

Comment: You should check your browser console.. what happens when you click on the submenu, do you get an error? Maybe your route isn't configured properly.. need more info to help you